# Pouchdb using ID to minimize docs revision how to query only the main document?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I try to design an app for managing files in a company.

A file have some attributes and have a lot of other files in.

I store file attribute in a document with 
"_id": "files:NAME_OF_FILE"

and I all the files in this file have
"_id": "files:NAME_OF_FILE:TYPE_OF_FILE:FILE_NAME"

and I tried to query only the first example.

I have know that can I do this easily with Map/Reduce query

but I read on PouchDB docs that we should prefer allDocs query over Map/Reduce query.

```
db.allDocs({
    startkey: 'files:',
    endkey: 'files:\ufff0'
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This code return all docs Main file and its contents...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If you know the ID of the document you want to retrieve, you can just use db.get as in:

```
db.get('mydoc', function(err, doc) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  // handle doc
});
```

Comment: No I miss explain myself I want to get all documents that have an ID who start by files: but don't have other things after example files:Foo files:foo2 but not files:foo2:doc1 files:foo2:doc2